# react matrerial ui Error: Objects are not valid as a React child If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, jsx

I am facing the error with the following code and there seems to be no fixes that is solving my issue.

```js
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/home')
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({
          data: response.data
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
}
```

response from server:

```js
{"data":{"count":{"monthly_blog_count":1,"total_blog_count":1,"monthly_poem_count":0,"total_poem_count":0,"monthly_song_count":0,"total_song_count":0,"monthly_graphics_count":1,"total_graphics_count":1},"latest_graphics":{"link":"ganesha.svg"},"latest_blog":{"title":"test","created":"2021-05-08T07:49:50.000Z","name":"Abhishek Banerjee"},"latest_blog_list":[{"title":"test","created":"2021-05-08T07:49:50.000Z","name":"Abhishek Banerjee"}]}}
```

```html
<Poems data={data} />
```

Here's the poem component edited as it's not allowing all code:
the base element is card. I took out code from the poem component since it's complaining not enough text. I have protypes validation on the component as well.

```js
const Poems = (props) => {
  const {
    data: count,
    'data.count.total_poem_count': totalPoemCount,
    'data.count.monthly_poem_count': monthlyPoemCount,
  } = props;

  return (
        <Card
          sx={{ height: '100%' }}
          {...props}
        >
          <Grid item>
            <Typography
              color="textPrimary"
              variant="h3"
            >
              { totalPoemCount }
            </Typography>
          </Grid>
          
          <Typography
            sx={{
              color: green[900],
              mr: 1
            }}
            variant="body2"
          >
            { monthlyPoemCount }
          </Typography>
     </card>
  );
};
```

**Edit**

putting `{ data?.data?.count?.total_poem_count }` works like a charm. But the proptypes validation is gone. Can anyone suggest me how to get proptypes as well working.

Comment: show the code  for Poems Component

Comment: @R.LM Posted the poem code.

Answer (score 1):

Best Practice is to use axios package for fetching api.

```
axios.get("http://localhost:8080/home")
.then((response) => {
        this.setState({
          data: response.data
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
```

passing data to component

```
<Poems data={this.state.data} />
```

child component

```
const Poems = ({ data }) => {
const dataToRender = data?.data


  return (
        <Card
          sx={{ height: '100%' }}
          {...props}
        >
          <Grid item>
            <Typography
              color="textPrimary"
              variant="h3"
            >
              { dataToRender.count.totalPoemCount }
            </Typography>
          </Grid>
          
          <Typography
            sx={{
              color: green[900],
              mr: 1
            }}
            variant="body2"
          >
            { dataToRender.count.monthlyPoemCount }
          </Typography>
     </card>
  );
};
```

<

Comment: It's not solving my problem. The props is undefined. The linter is complaining cannot find property count of undefined. Also the data is extracted from state before using `const { data } = this.state;` otherwise linter is complaining. Also the server response has snake case properties.

Comment: Try Object.values(monthlyPoemCount)